# Error "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities" in where clause inside the method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

When I execute my query:

```
rs.Select(x => x.id).ToArray();
```

I obtain this error:

> *The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities*

This is the method that generates the error (probably **func(x)**):

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> Compare<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> source, Func<TEntity, int> func)
{
     IQueryable<TEntity> res = source;

     if (!this.LBoundIsNull) res = res.Where(x => func(x) >= _lBound);
     if (!this.UBoundIsNull) res = res.Where(x => func(x) <= _uBound);

     return res;
}
```

I invoke the method in this mode:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.Number = new RangeValues(lBound, null);

using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
{
    var rs = db.documents;
    if (doc.Number != null) rs = doc.Numero.Compare(rs, x => x.number);

    long[] id = rs.Select(x => x.id).ToArray();
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: is `func(x)` meant to be translated to a Sql user defined funciton invocation ?

Comment: The error message that you're getting is telling you *exactly* what's wrong.  Invoking a function is not supported by EF.

Comment: **jbl**, `func(x)` is used to retrieve the value of the property (in this case `x.number`).

Comment: @Gigi You can't do it that way... You would need to do some expression-tree plumbing to do it.

Comment: LinqKit should be of some help here : https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit

Comment: Could just go to `IEnumerable<TEntity>` as well depending on performance.

Comment: @jbl LinqKit isn't a magic wand that you shake and magic appears... Show which part of LinqKit does what Gigi asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do what you want you will need to do something like:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> Compare<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> source, Expression<Func<TEntity, int>> func)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> res = source;

    if (!LBoundIsNull) 
    {
        Expression ge = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(func.Body, Expression.Constant(_lBound));
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(ge, func.Parameters);
        res = res.Where(lambda);
    }

    if (!UBoundIsNull)
    {
        Expression le = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(func.Body, Expression.Constant(_uBound));
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(le, func.Parameters);
        res = res.Where(lambda);
    }

    return res;
}
```

As you can see you'll need to do some expression-tree plumbing. You call the method in the same way as before.

Now... is it really possible to use [LinqKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/) as suggested by @jbl? Yes... By shaking a little the magic wand...

```
using LinqKit;

public static IQueryable<TEntity> Compare<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> source, Expression<Func<TEntity, int>> func)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> res = source;

    if (!LBoundIsNull)
    {
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> lambda = x => func.Invoke(x) >= _lBound;
        res = res.Where(lambda.Expand());
    }

    if (!UBoundIsNull)
    {
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> lambda = x => func.Invoke(x) <= _uBound;
        res = res.Where(lambda.Expand());
    }

    return res;
}
```

Note the use of the `Invoke()` and `Expand()` LinqKit methods.

Comment: @xantos The solution without _LinqKit_ is perfect and elegant. Thank you very much!